# When tried to add action menu for my custom module in xml got the extra tag data error

Tags: python, odoo

Here is my code:

```
<menuitem id="openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy" 
        parent="main_openacademy_menu"/>

<menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Courses" parents="openacademy_menu" 
        action="course_list_action"/>
```

When I run the code, I get this `AssertionError`:

> File "/home/mustafa/Odoo9/odoo-9.0/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 926, in >convert_xml_importrelaxng.assert_(doc)
>
> File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3373, in lxml.etree.*Validator.assert* (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:166352)
>
> AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data, line 3

Answer (score 3):

yes the issue here you are using parents instead of parent in menuitem tag

please try and change the line

```
<menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Courses" parent="openacademy_menu" 
        action="course_list_action"/>
```